# How can we align text horizontally using css?

Tags: html, css

We have some text in vertically align in html output:

```
Test 1 
Test 2 
Test 3 
Test 4
```

Now we would like these text `horizontally align` using `css` :

```
Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Test 4
```

Is there any way to do this using css ?

Updated :

```
<div class="horizontal">
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 2</div>
<div>Test 3</div>
<div>Test 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you share your html ? the solution will not be the same if you use div, span inline elements ...

Comment: Yes, there is. Show your attempt and HTML

Comment: if you have used <p> or <br/> tags then adding css alone may not be sufficient..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use `display: inline-block` to all div inside container

```css
.horizontal div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 2</div>
<div>Test 3</div>
<div>Test 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if we are not using any div inside main div then could you please assist me how I can achieve this functionality.
`<div class="horizontal">
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 4
</div>`

Comment: with no other rule text in `<div class="horizontal"> Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Test 4 </div>` is inline. Does your div embeded in another tag ? or do you have a specific css that can break the inline of the text ?

Answer (score 1):

Only use `flex`:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>test1</div>
<div>test2</div>
<div>test3</div>
<div>test4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use flexbox for this:

```css
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* this is the default behaviour, so not necessary to write it again */
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```